# Redirect dashboard after redirect in Angularjs codeigniter Hmvc

Tags: angularjs

i have login folder and having login route Provider.

```
$routeProvider.when('/admdashboard', {
    templateUrl : file_path+'/login/login/user',
    controller  : 'LoginCtrl'
});
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($location,$scope,$location,$http){
        $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:file_path+'/api/v1/user/login,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param($scope.text)
    }).success(function (data){
        if(data.response != 'error'){
            $location.path('/admin');
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

});
```

I can login successfully.but i am not able to direct?

After login successful how to redirect to administrator route provider

```
$routeProvider.when('/admdashboard', {
    templateUrl : file_path+'/admin/dashboard/dashboard_tiles',
    controller  : 'AdmDashboardController'
});
```

Comment: `$location.path('/admin');`  should be `$location.path('/admdashboard');`

Comment: its not redirecting even i use $location.path('/admdashboard');

Comment: the URL should change http://localhost/April_03/index.php/user_login/admin into http://localhost/April_03/index.php/admin/dashboard#/admdashboard

Comment: please check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) it might have what you are trying to do